# C# ListBox Import from Text File Crash

Tags: c#, import, crash, listbox

I am using this code to import text file to my ListBox

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
            foreach (string line in text)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(line);

            }
            listBox2.Items.Add("");
        }
```

It works fine for small text files, with 10 lines or so, but when I try to import bigger list, (4-5 megabytes) the program isn't responding and it's crashing.

Any help?

Comment: How many lines are in the 4-5 megabyte file?

Comment: What's the error when it crashes?

Comment: i could be wrong, but if i remember correctly there was some 64k limit on listboxes

Comment: @MatthewRz, 541207 lines.
DJBurb, it just stop responding.
DarkSquirrel42, what should I do then?

Comment: Putting that much in a listbox seems like overkill.  Usually listboxes are used for user interaction.  If you need that much information in a listbox, you may want to rethink things.  What exactly are you trying to do in your requirements?

Comment: @DJBurb what should I do then, if listBox wont work?

Comment: well it depends on what you are trying to do.  What are the requirements given to you

Comment: "It's crashing" surely means "It says 'not responding'".  Don't worry about that, your user won't be responding for a while either.

Answer (score 2):

Use the BufferedStream class in C# to improve performance.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx

Answer (score 1):

By using this:

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(text);
```

instead of this:

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
foreach (string line in text)
{
       listBox2.Items.Add(line);
}
```

you will speed up the execution at least 10-15 times because you are not invalidating listBox on every Item insert. 
I have measured with few thousand lines.

The bottleneck could also be `ReadAllLines` if your text has too many lines. Even though I can't figure out why you would be inserting so many lines, will user be able to find the line he/she needs?

**EDIT** OK then I suggest you to use BackgroundWorker, here is the code:

First you initialize BackGroundWorker:

```
 BackgroundWorker bgw;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }
```

Then you call it in your method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!bgw.IsBusy)
            {
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
                openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
                openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
                DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    listView1.BeginUpdate();
                    bgw.RunWorkerAsync(file);
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("File reading at the moment, try later!");
        }


        void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.EndUpdate();
        }
        void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = (string)e.Argument;
            TextReader t = new StreamReader(fileName);
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = t.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string nLine = line;
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(nLine); });
            }
        }
```

It will add each line when it reads it, you will have responsive UI, and lines won't affect the listBox before it finishes loading.

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

could use a stream to store the data:

```
class Test
{

public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

    //Create the file. 
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        AddText(fs, "This is some text");
        AddText(fs, "This is some more text,");
        AddText(fs, "\r\nand this is on a new line");
        AddText(fs, "\r\n\r\nThe following is a subset of characters:\r\n");

        for (int i=1;i < 120;i++)
        {
            AddText(fs, Convert.ToChar(i).ToString());

        }
    }

    //Open the stream and read it back. 
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
        }
    }
}

private static void AddText(FileStream fs, string value)
{
    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(value);
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

}

then you event handler

```
 privateasyncvoid Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding uniencoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string filename = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\Documents\userinputlog.txt";

        byte[] result = uniencoding.GetBytes(UserInput.Text);

        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            await SourceStream.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The file has 541207 lines, what should I do :)?

Comment: Do you have to display them all to the user? at one time?

Comment: that's not really important. They just need to import the list. No need of seeing it.

Comment: Then i would defianlty think of some sort of data stream.

Comment: How is the information going to be used?  After you read the information in, are you doing anything special with it?  There are many options that can be done, depending on what you are going to do with the data after you get it from the text file

Comment: chcek out the edits and the following link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Comment: File streams can hold way more data than any other, as it is just contoguous space in memory.

Comment: After load them into listbox, I want to cycle through each item.

Comment: and do what during the cycle of each item?

Comment: this will get you each line (see above) //Open the stream and read it back. 
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
        }
    }

Comment: Why don't you read each line into a List<string>?  Then you can use a foreach or linq to find what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It maybe simply not completing its job, and you should have to wait for more. Try with this solution:

http://www.bytechaser.com/en/articles/f3a3niqyb7/display-large-lists-in-listview-control-quickly.aspx

Comment: I'd rather use listBox than listView.

Comment: if the user does not need to see it, do not user a user control.  Use something in memory, like a stream or store it in a String.

Comment: yea you will have to drop the user controls like litBox and listView and use a stream

Comment: a listbox will just confuse the user, if they don't need to see it along with everything else you are having a problem with.

Comment: yeah, I agree, I read after my answer you don't need to show data to user. So you should be fine with: string[] x=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);

Answer (score 0):

Your application becomes unresponsive because it's waiting for the `ReadAllLines` method to complete and blocks the UI thread. You may want to read files on a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI. I cannot guarantee that the code below will work without errors but it should give you an idea on how to tackle the problem.

First of all, you'll need a method to append an item to the `ListBox`:

```
private void AddListBoxItem(string item)
{
    if(!InvokeRequired)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        var callback = new Action<string>(AddListBoxItem);
        Invoke(callback, new object[]{item});
    }
}
```

The method above checks if it is executed on UI thread and if yes, it simply adds an item to the `listBox2.Items` collection; if not, it creates a delegate from itself and invokes that delegate on UI thread.

Next, you'll need to move the code that reads the file to another thread and call `AddListBoxItem` method. For the sake of readability, let's put that into a separate method:

```
private void AddFileContentsToList(string fileName)
{
    using(var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            AddListBoxItem(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And now we will call the method on a separate thread:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var thread = new Thread(AddFileContentsToList);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Hope this helps!